# The 'https_local_ssl_verify' filter

Tags: posts, security

I have run into some WordPress code which does POST requests to API sites and in the POST parameters for the SSL property it has

```
$params = array( 'body' => $_POST, 'sslverify' => apply_filters('https_local_ssl_verify', false));
```

So why not simply put false or true?

Comment: What is wrong with using filter? Developers can modify default value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `apply_filters()` function lets plugins and themes override the value.  So yes, you *could* manually set `sslverify` to `false`.  The code snippet you included will set it to false *in the absence of any filter.*

Let's say I have a plugin that wants to force it to true.  I would add this:

```
add_filter( 'https_local_ssl_verify', '__return_true' );
```

The  `__return_true()` function is a special function in WordPress that automatically returns `true`.  So if I add this code to a plugin or my theme's `funtions.php` file, it will force your code above to set `'sslverify' => true`.

It all depends on your local setup and what you're trying to do with the site.  The use of `apply_filters()` merely makes things as flexible as possible.